# COUNTIFS throws parsing error: "#ERROR! Formula parse error."

Tags: google-sheets, count, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula

```
=Countifs(Answers!C:C; = "foo";Answers!D:D;<D4;Answers!J:J;>D4)
```

I conducted a survey, in which people told me the clock-times they typically
enter (Sheet 'Answers', Column D) a specific facility named 'foo' (Sheet 'Answers', Column C) and when they typically leave it (Sheet 'Answers', Column J).

I want to get the number of people in 'foo' at a specific point in time ('D4'), so my approach is to count everyone who answered 'foo' and whose entry time was before the time in question and whose leaving time was after the time in question.

When I use the formula I get "#ERROR. Error while parsing formula."(roughly translated).

Am I using the formula incorrectly or is there a syntax error in there?

Comment: Try without the semi-colons at the end of your ranges (i.e. "Answers!C:C;") - I've never had to use those in my formulas.

Comment: @opowell That gives a different error. "Countifs expects arguments in pairs of two." The 'autocomplete'-helper is also in fovor of semicolons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following formula:

```
=countifs(Answers!C:C;"foo";Answers!D:D;"<"&D4;Answers!J:J;">"&D4)
```

Or (depending on your locale):

```
=countifs(Answers!C:C,"foo",Answers!D:D,"<"&D4,Answers!J:J,">"&D4)
```